Awsume: Error "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use"
I installed awsume using pip, I configured ~/.aws/configure as I have in another computer:
[profile profile-test]
region=eu-west-1
credential_process=*corporate_login_tool* -t arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/project-admin


When typing awsume profile-test in terminal, in my previous computer this would open a browser window and set de env credentials. However, with this new install I am getting and error in the browser Some failures occurred during the authentication a second browser window opened with a connecting problem and in the terminal a message saying OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
Awsume configuration has not many options, I tried changing the aliases, reinstalling, using pipx, etc; without any advancement.
I tried looking for another services using the same port, or another python scripts running.
The corporate tool that logs into the aws console works fine standalone and returns the credentials correctly. Has anyone encountered this problem?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, python 3.10.12, awsume version is 4.5.4, pip version is 22.0.2.
